# Unwind Segue doesn't exit the view : Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, unwind-segue

I code with Xcode v6.1.1

I have two classes: Reports, and Admin.
When we are in Reports (first view), I tap on admin button, and the Admin view appears (second view).
When I tap on exit button (in Admin view), I would like that Admin view disappears and Reports comes back.

I don't know if I make error in code, but NSLog appears from prepareForUnwind.
Unwind segue appears in storyboard and link to "exit". Unwind segue identifier : "unwindToContainerVC" Action : prepareForUnwind:

Here is my code :

Admin.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Reports.h"

@interface Admin : UIViewController

-(IBAction)prepareForUnwind:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;

@end
```

Admin.m:

```
#import "Admin.h"


@interface Admin ()

@end

@implementation Admin

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)prepareForUnwind:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    NSLog(@"Called unwind action");
}




@end
```

Have I to put something in Reports.h or Reports.m ?
Thanks !

Comment: Your `prepareForUnwind` method should be in `Reports`, the VC you are unwinding TO, not Admin.

Comment: @pbasdf Ok I've put prepareForUnwind in Reports, but in storyboard I've to implement prepareForUnwind with button ?

Comment: Ctrl-drag from the button to the "Exit" icon, then select `prepareForUnwind` from the list of possible unwind actions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you wire up the Exit Button to the "exit" action in your storyboard?

Make sure you followed all of the instructions here: [Using Unwind Segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html)

Comment: Yes, I've dragged exitButton on "exit" in storyboard. :(